# Web component tester 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: selenium, polymer-1.0, web-component-tester

I installed web component tester for my polymer application. Running wct command from my project is throwing me this error. Has anyone encountered this issue?

```
TestM:my-app 212394486$ wct
Installing and starting Selenium server for local browsers
Selenium server running on port 58961
Web server running on port 2000 and serving from /Users/212394486/Desktop/projects/responsemax/resmax-app
firefox 41               Tests failed: <html><head><title>504 Gateway Timeout</title></head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this 502 issue fixed. It was due to proxy. In your environment variable / bashprofile, you have to add export no_proxy = "*.local, localhost, 127.0.0.1"